# How to get checkbox value immediately after setting the state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I want the checkbox value immediately after setting the state.
on the below code i want the checkbox value inside the handelchange after setting the state
I have added console over there

```
state = {
status: false,
}

handleChange = (event) => {
this.setState((prevState) => {
   return {
      ...prevState,
      status: !prevState.status
   }
})
 ====console.log(this.state.status)====//if it checked and set i should get true
 }


<Form.Check
type="checkbox" 
label="Consigne temporaire"
value={this.state.status}
onChange={this.handleChange}
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback as the second argument to `this.setState`, which is guaranteed to run after the state has been updated (see the [docs on `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate))

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {
     ...prevState,
     status: !prevState.status
  }
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.status)
})
```

Comment: can we do this with functional components?

Comment: @maazakn Doesn't work for function components, but you can use `useEffect` in that case, with the state variable in the dependency array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use useEffect or componentDidUpdate and bind the checkbox state with it.

```
state = {
status: false,
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.status !== this.state.status) {
    console.log('Checkbox State change',this.state.status)
  }
}

handleChange = (event) => {
this.setState((prevState) => {
   return {
      ...prevState,
      status: !prevState.status
   }
})
 ====console.log(this.state.status)====//if it checked and set i should get true
 }


<Form.Check
type="checkbox" 
label="Consigne temporaire"
value={this.state.status}
onChange={this.handleChange}
 />
```

Comment: Can i get small example on that

Comment: added code snippet.